# Workflow history is not available for the Completed workflows in SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, nintex, workflow-history, sp-online

We have Nintex workflow implemented in SharePoint Online.

If the workflow is completed, then there is no data available under Completed workflow.

[image]

But if the workflow is In progress then the workflow data is available under running workflow.

Also, this behavior is observed with items that are more than 1 month old.

Can anyone help here to understand what is exactly happening here?